# Prefix a(n)- in Sanskrit and English

Tags: etymology, sanskrit

In learning about the three Buddhist marks of existence - referred to by the Sanskrit words anatman (lack of permanent self), anitya (impermanence) and dukkha (suffering) - I was interested to learn that "anatman" comes from an- as in "not" and "atman" as in "soul". Literally "no soul" - it seems like a similar morphological construction to words in English prefaced with a- or an-.

I was wondering if "anitya" shared a similarly interesting etymology, but I wasn't able to find one on Wiktionary or through Googling.

Does anyone know where the Sanskrit word "anitya" comes from?

Comment: I have edited the title to bring out the comparativist content of this interesting question.

Comment: I'm not sure why - was the question as it stood OT? The title now doesn't make sense in relation to the answer you've provided.

Comment: Feel free to change it back. I was only trying to discourage further "close" votes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

anitya is a compound of the negative prefix a- and nitya- “lasting, permanent”.

As you point out, the negative particle is an- before a vowel and a- before a consonant (as here). English words with negative a- and an- are all borrowings from Greek, and those with in- (im- etc.) are from Latin (like "impermanence"). The authentic English cognate is un-.

Comment: But Greek and Sanskrit a(n)-, Latin in-, and Germanic un- (and Slavonic ne-) all derive from the same Indo-European privative prefix ṇ-

Comment: @ColinFine. Yes. Did I say anything different?

Comment: I see that my _But_ could be read as disagreeing with you - I didn't mean it that way. I meant "And, further,"

Comment: No, the negative *particle" is \*ne > Skr. *ni*. \*.n is it's binding form, but devanagari has a habbit of contracting phrases into words, so that invariant reduplication with -ni- should be expected, right?